# Moskito integration is not working as part of non maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, ajdt

Im working on Moskito integration with a web app (non maven project).

**

- Maven Project No Issue:(its working good)

**

Im using annotation (AOP) to monitor a class/method. here when i add annotation on class/method level and compile a .java file it generates two .class files

example.. i have a class called Order.java. here if i keep @Monitor annotation and compile Order.java it generates two classes one is normal Order.class and other one is Order$Clause1.class

since i have added below plugin on pom.xml so its generationg additional .class files

```
        *<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
                        <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>*
```

BUT
**

- Non Maven Project having Issue:

**

in non maven project the additional Order$Clause1.class is not generated on /classes folder. due to that im not able to monitor those class/methods on moskito application.
(even i have added AJDT plugin also on Eclipse and added all required jars as well. app runs good on moskito but only class/methods are not monitored on moskito) 
How to do it/ generate additional .class files for moskito on a normal poject(non maven) ?
your ideas helps me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved, by making maven project convert to aspectJ project 
and then add moskito-aop jar to aspectJ compiler classpath. done